# How to change the application name based on SIM card information?

Tags: android

I need to rename my Android application based on the country code obtained from the SIM card. I can easily get the country code from the `TelephonyManager` class as shown below.

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr =   
    (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = mTelephonyMgr.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

How would I change the name of my application based on the obtained country code?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Application name is a static value that Android retrieves from `AndroidManifest.xml`  file. And it can not be changed dynamically (as far as I know).

When your application name is displayed, your code is not even running. So from this point of view, there is no theoretical way to change your name unless user runs your app.

All these assuming your are taking about application name that is displayed in "Applications" screens, from where users start applications.

Answer (score 0):

Application name may be adapted to some level. It is taken from the AndroidManifest.xml, but it can  be  string value from resources. So, if you have string resources adapted to different languages, name of your application can adapt as well. Of course, it happens only when user sets certain language for the phone, then Android does the job for you (supposing that you provided string resources for that language).